# How to prevent "upx -d" on an UPX packed executable?

Tags: packers, upx

I recently read a [tweet](https://twitter.com/corkami/status/417604202236350464/photo/1) from [Ange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/188/ange) about a technique to fool UPX when the option `-d` (decompress) is called.

I would like to know how this is working and, what are the technique to prevent an UPX packed executable to be decompressed through `upx -d` (if possible for, both, Linux and Windows).

Comment: Of course @blabb's answer prevents `upx -d` but you should be aware that Generic Unpackers such as RL Depacker can still unpack such files.

Comment: If you want to, protect your UPX output with Denuvo/VMProtect/enigma protector/anything of this nature and no-one can decompress it.

Comment: @JessieLesbian not to be picky but "no-one can decompress it" is (**simply**) not really true. It's like saying "No one can break into this system, it's 100% secure." same thing here, "No one can decompress this malware, it's 100% secure."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UPX doesn't check the unpacking stub's integrity, and just blindly restores the data from the stored information, not from the actual execution.

Since UPX is open-source and documented ([commented IDB](https://corkami.googlecode.com/files/upx-idb.zip)), it's easy to modify its and actually do something extra (anti-debug, patch, decryption, jump to real entrypoint...) that will be lost when 'upx -d' is used.

Such UPX hack is not uncommon in malware.

Comment: If I get it right, it only requires to modify the checksum of the packed executable... Or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: @perror did you figure this out?

Comment: I appeared to be true (at the time I tested it). So, modifying the checksum of the executable won't prevent to execute it, but will render the decompression a bit more difficult (because you need to bypass this checksum verification before applying the decompression).

Answer (score 13):

Fooling `upx -d` can be as simple as one byte patch here is a small sample.

Pack the MS-Windows standard `calc.exe`, hexedit one byte and result is an undepackable executable with `upx -d` (this is **not** `corrupting` the exe, the exe will run and can be unpacked manually). Only unpacking with the `-d` switch wont work.

1. create a new folder `foolupx`:

   ```
    foolupx:\>md foolupx
   ```
2. copy `calc.exe` to the newly created folder:

   ```
    foolupx:\>copy c:\WINDOWS\system32\calc.exe foolupx\upxedcalc.exe
        1 file(s) copied.
   ```
3. pack the renamed `calc.exe`:

   ```
    foolupx:\>upx .\foolupx\upxedcalc.exe
    Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
    Copyright (C) 1996 - 2011
    UPX 3.08w       Markus Oberhumer, Laszlo Molnar & John Reiser   Dec 12th 2011

        File size         Ratio      Format      Name
       --------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
         114688 ->     56832   49.55%    win32/pe     upxedcalc.exe

    Packed 1 file.
   ```
4. Create a duplicate of the packed `calc.exe` for hexediting and compare the files. The difference is one byte in the PE header section named `UPX0` changed to `BPX0`:

   ```
    foolupx:\>copy .\foolupx\upxedcalc.exe .\foolupx\modupxedcalc.exe
        1 file(s) copied.

    foolupx:\>fc .\foolupx\upxedcalc.exe .\foolupx\modupxedcalc.exe
    Comparing files .\FOOLUPX\upxedcalc.exe and .\FOOLUPX\MODUPXEDCALC.EXE
    000001E8: 55 42
   ```
5. Uncompress both files with the `-d` switch. One will be unpacked, the other will not be unpacked:

   ```
    foolupx:\>upx -d .\foolupx\modupxedcalc.exe
    Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
    Copyright (C) 1996 - 2011
    UPX 3.08w       Markus Oberhumer, Laszlo Molnar & John Reiser   Dec 12th 2011

        File size         Ratio      Format      Name
       --------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
        upx: .\foolupx\modupxedcalc.exe: CantUnpackException: file is modified/hacked/protected; take care!!!

    Unpacked 0 files.

    foolupx:\>upx -d .\foolupx\upxedcalc.exe
    Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
    Copyright (C) 1996 - 2011
    UPX 3.08w       Markus Oberhumer, Laszlo Molnar & John Reiser   Dec 12th 2011

          File size         Ratio      Format      Name
     --------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
     114688 <-     56832   49.55%    win32/pe     upxedcalc.exe

    Unpacked 1 file.

    foolupx:\>
   ```

Comment: **first of all - great answer!** - Just have to ask; is the one-byte-patch arbitrary chosen in this answer or can it be more? e.g I thought of changing UPX's "signature" (the text "UPX" which is very common in UPX-packed exe's), to something like, DTK (`randomly made up`)  or would that corrupt it ? (as in running it and changing it back, and then `upx -d`)

Comment: adding another comment just to point: if I can improve my comment just point it out! :) Wishes from Sweden!